# How to autoOpen jquery UI dialog at a specific time

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Is there a way I can use jQuery UI dialog to auto open after 5 seconds when the page finish loading, not just to autoload on page load. I used `autoOpen: true`.

Its working but on the page load. My question is how can I set the time in seconds to pop out the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the autoOpen to false and try:

```
;$(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydialog').dialog('open');
  }, 5000); // 5000 = 5secs

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true 
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```